# Read a properties file error

Tags: java, properties, runtime-error, configuration-files

im trying to read a config.properties file but i get this error: "An exception occurred: java.io.FileNotFoundException  "

I'm using this code:

```
Properties config = new Properties();
InputStream configInput = null;     
private Connection getDBConnection() {
    try{
        configInput = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
        config.load(configInput);
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(config.getProperty("Error en archivo propiedades" + e.getMessage()));

    }
    Connection dbConnection = null;
    try {
        Class.forName(config.getProperty("DRIVER"));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  ........ continue
```

i have the class and the config properties in the same package:
[See the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07FQV.png)

Comment: The current file path at run time, is **not** the source file path.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a **maven** project such a file is supposed to be in

```
src/main/resources/ceiba/
```

It still would be packed with the classes in the class path (typically inside a .jar file). It is not a File on the filesystem, but a resource:

```
    configInput = Clase.class.getResourceAsStream("config.properties"); // or:
    configInput = Clase.class.getResourceAsStream("/ceiba/config.properties");
```

By the way: in general `Class.forName` no longer is needed (since some years).

Answer (score 0):

Your code try to get file in root folder and the file is on ceiba folder.

[Examples](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/)